# cakephp image uploading with image magick

Tags: php, image, imagemagick, cakephp-2.0

I am implementing ImageMagick in my CakePHP based website.
I want to upload a 3000*3000px image and I want to create a thumbnail of that image as well. Right now I am using the the following code to upload images:

```
$w = 1024;
$destFile = $uploadDir.$imagePath;
$h = number_format(($size[1] / $size[0]) * $w, 0, ',', '');//$size[1]/6;
$dest = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
$src = imagecreatefromjpeg($image['tmp_name']);
imagecopyresampled($dest, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h, $size[0], $size[1]);
imagejpeg($dest,$destFile, 25);
```

The code stops working when uploading a 3000*3000px image.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `this code is not work anymore` does not help at all. Could you please be more precise? Also, you suggest that it did work once. Maybe explain what caused your code not being functional anymore? And how is CakePHP related to this question?

Comment: what is the max filesize specified in your php.ini ?